# How I can align the header text of the ExpandableListview to the extreme left?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[image]

I am using an Expandable Listview, but I want the "Store 1" text aligned to the extreme left.
I have set the GroupIndicator to null, but then it only hides the group indicator.
I want the text to start at the extreme left.
I do not want the space.

How can I achieve this??

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:id="@+id/expandableListViewwrittensales"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout" />


</RelativeLayout>`
```

Group Text xml .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/store"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTitle"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you need to make change in your custom layout which you have used in group layout

Comment: post xml file where "store 1" textview is

Comment: @FrankN.Stein - Perfect..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line from your Group layout:

```
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
```

Also replace the **deprecated** `fill_parent` with `match_parent`